# Why does $(U\circ \exp )^{\prime} = 1/h(U\circ \exp)$ in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, derivatives, probability-distributions

Let $F$ be some continuous cumulative distribution function. It is stated that for $U = (1/\overline{F})^{\leftarrow}$ and for $h = \frac{f}{\overline{F}}$ with $\overline{F} = 1-F$ and $f$ the density associated to $F$.

Why does $(U\circ \exp )^{\prime} = 1/h(U\circ \exp)$ in this case?

My attempts:

$(U\circ \exp)^{\prime}(x)=U^{\prime}(\exp(x))\times \exp(x)$

and

$U^{\prime}(t) = 1/{(\frac{1}{\overline F})^{\prime}((1/\overline{F})^{\leftarrow}(t))}$

and

$(\frac{1}{\overline F})^{\prime}=\frac{f}{\overline{F}^{2}}$

such that

$U^{\prime}(t)=1/{(\frac{f}{\overline{F}^{2}}((1/\overline{F})^{\leftarrow}(t))}=\frac{1}{h(U(t))}\times \overline{F}(U(t))$

So now, how do I evaluate $\overline{F}(U(t))$?

Edit: $F^{\leftarrow}(t):= \inf\{ x: F(x) \geq 1 - t\} $, i.e. the quantile function.

Comment: I think your notation is not very clear. $1/\overline{F}$ is not a distribution function. So $(1/\overline{F})^\leftarrow$ seems to be not well defined. Which text are you reading? You might want to copy it with "Mathpix".

Comment: Also $F^\leftarrow$ does not seem to be the quantile function?